# Make unique rows with laravel factory

Tags: laravel, factory, laravel-seeding, laravel-factory

In my definition method I got this:

```
$users = []; // List of user's ids
$items = []; // List of Item's ids

return [
    'user' => $this->faker->randomElement($user),
    'item'=> $this->faker->randomElement($item),
];
```

This makes duplicated rows, (multiple rows with same user column and item column).

e.g: my databse

```
0: {id:'1',user:'1',item:'1'}
1: {id:'2',user:'5',item:'4'}
2: {id:'3',user:'7',item:'12'}
3: {id:'4',user:'1',item:'3'}
4: {id:'5',user:'1',item:'1'} // Duplicated
5: {id:'6',user:'10',item:'11'}
```

How can I make this to be unique? (Just one row with unique user and item)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most pragmatic approach is simply to do this outside of the factory. While manually assigning the value to each factory creation.

```
foreach ($users as $userId) {
    foreach ($items as $itemId) {
        factory(YourModel::class)->create(
            [
                'user' => $userId,
                'item' => $itemId,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```